# .attr('disabled', 'disabled') or .attr('disabled', true) for disabling input

Tags: jquery

Both `.attr('disabled', 'disabled')` and `.attr('disabled', true)` work in my code, but I'm just wondering: which among the two is more efficient and/or which is more used? Is there really a difference? Performance-wise, maybe?

Comment: It's often a good idea to read the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc-1). Quote: *Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the `value` property of input elements, the `disabled` property of inputs and buttons, or the `checked` property of a checkbox. The `.prop()` method should be used to set `disabled` and checked` instead of the `.attr()` method.*

Comment: @nbrooks Thanks for the enlightenment :-)

Comment: This close reason makes no sense.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Should not make any difference. But from jQuery 1.6+ you should use:

```
$('input').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: If using TypeScript, then this option won't transpile.