# Retain select tag value if user doesn't confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

The ajax is fired when user confirms, but if user cancels the confirm dialog still the select tag value changes though ajax isn't fired. I want something like if user cancels then select tag should retain it's previous value.
I have this:

```
<select name="ss" id="<?=$row['id'];?>" onchange="_changeStatus(this.value,'<?=$row['id'];?>');">
   <option value='Paid'>Paid</option>
   <option value='Verified'>Verified</option>
   <option value='Inprocess'>Inprocess</option>
   <option value='Chargeback'>Chargeback</option>
</select>
```

And This:

```
function _changeStatus(v,i){
       if(confirm("Sure to Update")){
       $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'change-status.php',
            data: {val:v,eid:i,actionid:1},
            success: function (res) {
              if(res!="scr"){
                alert("Unexpected Error, Page will be refreshed !");
                window.location.reload();
              }

            }
          });
     }
    }
```

Comment: Instead you can try blocking UI by showing loading image if you upload files using ajax

Comment: there is a progress bar for upload progress, how can i show that only while rest elements get hide.

Comment: Block uui in the beforeSend function and the unblock ui in the complete function in your ajax code.. For blocking ui there are number of ways google it..

Answer (score 0):

If your form has multiple input elements, `$("uform :input")` will return an array of them. You have use index and set property accordingly. You can use something like below

```
$($("uform :input")[0]).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use correct selector in you JS
If udorm is an ID of form and input is a tag inside -

> $("#uform input").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

OR

> $("#uform input").prop('disabled', true);

See here about differ [.attr('disabled', 'disabled') or .attr('disabled', true) for disabling input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947105/attrdisabled-disabled-or-attrdisabled-true-for-disabling-input/24947125)

Also be sure you have linked jQuery. 
If you don't you can set ID for input-tag and disable it by this

Eg. ID of you input tag is "loadInput"

> document.getElementById('loadInput').disabled = true;

Comment: Can I see whole HTML?